# Can't reverse eloquent relationships in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

On my Laravel app, I'm currently working on users being able to "block" other users.

In my users model, I try to define the "blocked" relationships between users:

```
public function blockedOfMine() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('CommendMe\Models\User', 'blocked', 'user_id', 'blocked_id');
}

public function blockedBy() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('CommendMe\Models\User', 'blocked', 'blocked_id', 'user_id');
}

public function blocked() {
    return $this->blockedOfMine()->get();
}

public function blockedMe() {
    return $this->blockedBy()->get();
}

public function isBlocked(User $user) {
    return (bool) $this->blocked()->where('id', $user->id)->count();
}

public function hasBlockedMe(User $user) {
    return (bool) $this->blockedMe()->where('id', $user->id)->count();
}
```

Basically, this model is only trying to figure out whether a user has blocked another user (function isBlocked) or whether a user has been blocked by another user (function hasBlockedMe).

Now, the first function works just fine, however the second one doesn't, despite them being completely the same:

```
if (Auth::user()->isBlocked($user)) {
   return redirect()->back()->with('info', 'You cannot message blocked users.');    
}
if (Auth::user()->hasBlockedMe($user)) {
   return redirect()->back()->with('info', 'This user has blocked communications with you.');   
}
```

so if I try to message a user who is blocked, I get the message "You cannot message blocked users.", but the message goes through perfectly fine when I try to message a user who has blocked me.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the schema for the tables?

Comment: It's nothing complicated, really. The blocked table has an 'id' (auto incremented primary key), 'user_id', and 'blocked_id'. Both user_id and blocked_id are referencing the primary key of the users table, which is 'id'.

Comment: I think your problem is in the wheres. I think you're just getting lucky the first one is working. Probably first should be blocked_id and the second should be user_id. ie `where('blocked_id', $user->id)` for isBlocked and `where('user_id', $user->id)` for hasBlockedMe

Comment: Nope, nope. It was just me being dumb. I clarified this in my answer.

Comment: Haha, not dumb. We all make mistakes, glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright well I'm not sure if I should post this as an "answer" or not, seeing as the problem me being an idiot, but it turns out I was logged into the wrong account that uses the same avatar, so I got confused. This is why the message was being sent despite being "blocked". Whoops...